# How to convert the parameters of multi-factors cheyette model (quasi-Gaussian model) from tenors to factors?

Tags: interest-rates, derivatives, short-rate, heath-jarrow-morton

The book ["Interest Rate Modeling" by Andersen and Piterbarg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0984422110) is an extermely fascinating book on interest rate derivatives.
Recently, I have encoutered some issues while reading this book. 
**How to convert the parameters of multi-factors cheyette model from tenors to factors while keeping the variance of $S(t,T)$(Swap Rate) unchanged?** 
When calibrateing multi-factors cheyette model, we first calibrate the parameters for each tenor, similar to one-factor model.Then, we convert the parameters for multi-tenors into parameters for multi-factors. Right? 
In the section 12.1.7 and 13.3.2 of the book "interest rate modeling", Andersen and Piterbarg tell us how to convert the parameters via restoring the variance/covariance of $f(t,T+ \delta_i)$. this is all well and good. 
But my question is how to restore the variance of $S(t,T+\delta_i)$ ? Because the converted model must be able to Marked to Market.
In particular, the instataneous forward rate
$$f(t,T) = f(0,T) + \left(x_t + yG(t,T)\right)\frac{h(T)}{h(t)} \tag{1}$$
$$x_t \sim N(0, \lambda^2\sigma^2 ) \tag{2}$$
let $D$ denotes the cholesky decomposed factors for correlation coefficent matrixs of $f(t,T+\delta_i)$. so we obtian
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1\sigma_1&0&\cdots&0 \\\\
0&\lambda_2\sigma_2&\cdots&0 \\\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\\\
0&0&\cdots&\lambda_n\sigma_n \\\\
    \end{pmatrix}= H_f 
\begin{pmatrix}
\eta_{11}&\eta_{12}&\cdots&\eta_{1n} \\\\
\eta_{21}&\eta_{22}&\cdots&\eta_{2n} \\\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\\\
\eta_{n1}&\eta_{n2}&\cdots&\eta_{nn} \\\\
\end{pmatrix}^T \tag{3}$$
where, the n×n matrix of $H^f$ denotes the factors's parameters. hence
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\eta_{11}&\eta_{12}&\cdots&\eta_{1n} \\\\
\eta_{21}&\eta_{22}&\cdots&\eta_{2n} \\\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\\\
\eta_{n1}&\eta_{n2}&\cdots&\eta_{nn} \\\\
\end{pmatrix}^T = H^{-1}_f \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1\sigma_1&0&\cdots&0 \\\\
0&\lambda_2\sigma_2&\cdots&0 \\\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\\\
0&0&\cdots&\lambda_n\sigma_n \\\\
    \end{pmatrix}D \tag{4}$$
So far, I have no questions. let's move on to simulate the $P(t,T)$.
$$\ln P(t,T) =\ln P(0,T) -x_tG(t,T) - 0.5*G^T(t,T)yG(t,T) \tag{5}$$
where,
$$G(t,T) = \int_t^T{\frac{h(s)}{h(t)}\text{d}s} \tag{6}$$
I found it is impossible to restore the variance of $P(t,T+\delta_i)$, not to mention restoring the variance of the Swap Rate. Is it ?

**The following is my thought process for problem-solving:** 
The goal of the convertion is to restore the variance of $S(t,T+\delta_i)$, while keeping the correlation cofficient of $f(t,T+\delta_i)$ unchanged. And the correlation cofficient of $S(t,T+\delta_i)$ and the variance of $f(t,T+\delta_i)$ are unknown and not important.

Let's define the variance/covariance
$$\Sigma_f =\begin{pmatrix} y_1&0&\cdots&0\\ 0&y_2&\cdots&0\\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\  0&0&\cdots&y_n\end{pmatrix} \rho
   \begin{pmatrix} y_1&0&\cdots&0\\ 0&y_2&\cdots&0\\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\  0&0&\cdots&y_n\end{pmatrix} \tag{7}$$
Obviously, the correlation cofficient of $\Sigma_f$ is $\rho$.

Furthermore, accroding to formula(1) and (2), obtain
$$\Sigma_f = H_f^T \Sigma_x H_f \tag{8}$$
Hence,
$$\Sigma_x = (H_f^{-1})^T \Sigma_f H_f^{-1} = (H_f^{-1})^T Y\rho Y H_f^{-1}\tag{9}$$
where, $Y = diag\left(\begin{pmatrix} y_1&y_2&\cdots&y_n\end{pmatrix}^T \right)$.

And let denote the variance/covariance of $S(t, T+\delta_i)$ as
$$\Sigma_s = M_s^T \Sigma_x M_s \tag{10}$$
where,
$$M_s(t,T+\delta_i) = \frac{\partial S}{\partial x} (t,T+\delta_i) \tag{11}$$

Accroding to formula (9) and (10), obtain
$$\Sigma_s = M_s^T (H_f^{-1})^T Y \rho Y H_f^{-1} M_s \tag{12}$$
Remember, we only need to restore the variance of Swap rate. Hence
$$ diag\left(M_s^T (H_f^{-1})^T Y \rho Y H_f^{-1} M_s\right)= \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_{s,1}^2&\sigma_{s,2}^2& \cdots& \sigma_{s,n}^2\end{pmatrix}^T \tag{13}$$
let simplify the formula(13), obtain
$$diag\left(A^T Z\rho Z A\right) = \begin{pmatrix} 1& 1&\cdots& 1\end{pmatrix}^T \tag{14}$$
Where, 
$A= H_f^{-1}M_s$ is asymmetric invertible matrix, 
$Z = diag\left(\begin{pmatrix} \frac{y_1}{\sigma_{s,1}}&\frac{y_2}{\sigma_{s,2}}&\cdots&\frac{y_n}{\sigma_{s,n}}\end{pmatrix}^T
\right)$.

At last, my question is,
(a) how to solve the formula (14)? Does an analytic solution of $Z$ exist ? 
(b) In order for $A^T Z\rho Z A$ be a correlation cofficient matrix, what conditions does $Z$ need to satisfy ?

Any help and hints are very much appreciated.